# What is not possible to do with Spring XML defined context?

Tags: java, spring

The options are: a)Autowire beans by their type
                 b)Inject values from property file
                 c)Use annotation in defined bean
                 d)Override beans defined in a parent application context 
                 e)None of the above

Possible multiple options:

Comment: apparently: googling this or reading a text-book on the subject, is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can autowire beans by their type. But we cant inject the values from the properties file. And rest options seems correct
So b option may be. Am I right ?